# How to keep track of debug code in DEV branch, but remove it on MASTER

Tags: git, githooks, lint

I have a problem related with GIT.
Imagine this branch schema:

```
 MASTER
   |
  DEV
   |
FEATURE1
```

Where "**DEV**" is the branch where we review the code, and the debug code (in this case, `console.log` and similar) should NOT be included there, and 'FEATURE1' is where I do my work, and for that I want to keep debug code tracked.

I'm using 2 hooks (pre-commit & post-commit):

[pre-commit](https://pastebin.com/jhDVQhES)

[post-commit](https://pastebin.com/yNQJK6an)

This works if I commit the changes in the "**DEV**" branch, since it basically clones the changes, stashes them before the commit and un-stashes them after, but that misses the point of having a "**FEATURE**" branch, and will only allow me to have the debug code locally (I might need to full checkout the project in a different device and I want to be able to recover my debug code...)

The workflow I got until now is basically commiting normally to the FEATURE branch, and then cherrypick it in the DEV branch like so:
`git cherry-pick -x COMMITid --no-commit; git commit --reuse-message=COMMITid`

**---- TD;DR ----**

I'm looking for a way to remove console.log when commiting/merging to specific branches (*master* & **dev**, in this case)

Comment: Normal workflow should not rely on cherry-picking.

Comment: Some sort of build-time preprocessing or super-cheap runtime checks are the usuals for debug code, stripping out debug scaffolding entirely is for surprising and basically unheard-of situations.

Comment: I guess I have to have negociate it with my Project Manager...

Comment: Someone suggested to commit just specific lines (basically to exclude debug lines), but that is way too underproductive, I want to automate that.

Answer (score 1):

## Debug code

You should use `#if (C# Reference)` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-if) for debug code.

```
#if DEBUG
    Console.WriteLine("Debug version");
#endif
```

---

## Debug artifacts

Stop keeping debug artifacts (*"console.log and similar"*) with your source code.

Comment: Hi, it's a nativescript project (Vue.js). Anyhow, this is something I would like to handle in the git workflow.
You´re still right about the debug artifacts, but since it's a project from scratch, it was to be like that till the MVP is reached.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to wrap your statements if blocks for an environment variable that gets set at runtime that way there's no need to remove it

Comment: Hi, it's not about the debug code running, is about "being there", doesn't help in the code review. It's more code to read and doesn't bring value for the review.